# jquery not working when i'm not putting it inside a jQuery(document).ready

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".test").click(function() {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

When I try not to put :

```
jQuery(".test").click(function() {
            alert(1);
        });
```

inside a `jQuery(document).ready()` it won't work.

What do you think is the cause of that one? I already loaded the custom script that has that function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/customScript.js"></script>
```

Any answer would be appreciated and rewarded.

Thanks!

Comment: I think, Amadan's answer is correct. Thanks For answering @BryanRoss, because of that, I'll give you an UP! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading it in `<head>`, then your `.test` hasn't loaded yet at the time when your code executes. Thus, `jQuery(".test")` returns `[]`, so the `click` event gets attached to nothing. If you move your `<script>` to the last thing in `<body>`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is normal and correct.

When you say:

```
jQuery(".test").click(function() {
   alert(1);
});
```

It means "find all elements that exist *right now* with the class 'test' and assign a click handler to those elements". If you put such code outside the document ready then the browser will not have parsed any HTML that is after that bit of script so it will not find any elements defined further down the page - they don't exist in the DOM yet.

Putting the code inside document.ready (or in an onload event handler) means that it won't be run until the whole page has been parsed, at which point all elements will exist and can be accessed from your code. (It should also work if you put it right at the bottom of the page after all the HTML.)